unitest enzyme react-youtube
I'm currently using the react-youtube library to render this and make use of the following function
const handleVideoClick = () => {
    setVideoClicked(true);
}; 

I'm new to writing unit tests and would like to know if anyone can guide me on how to write tests for this using Enzyme and Jest
<HeaderModal>
    <YouTube className='video'
             videoId="0JyfWpUJs9U"
             onPlay={handleVideoClick} />
</HeaderModal>


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
